# C++ 11 How to reference class methods in other classes or source files

Tags: c++, class, c++11, makefile, static-methods

I'm back to C++ after a lapse of several years with a proof of concept.  I have a hpp file that defines a class, a cpp file with the class methods, and a main.cpp for testing.  I'm attempting to create a tcp server that runs in its own thread (only called once).  I started with all the code in the same cpp file and got it to work but I get compile errors now that I've put the class and the methods in their own files.

I've searched but not found anything that works.  I've tried using extern, the 'singleton' method, etc. which all result in various error messages.  I know that I'm not providing a correct reference to the methods.

`tcpserver.hpp`:

```
#ifndef __TCP_SERVER_HPP_INCLUDED__   
#define __TCP_SERVER_HPP_INCLUDED__   

#include <string>

class Server {
    public:

        static void *tcp_server(void * dummy);
        static void hello();
        static int parseCmd(const char *cmd, char *reply);
        static int copystring(char *reply, const char *msg);

    private:

};

#endif
```

`tcpserver.cpp`, with class methods as stubs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>      // Needed for memset
#include <sys/socket.h> // Needed for the socket functions
#include <netdb.h>      // Needed for the socket functions
#include <string.h>

#include "tcpserver.hpp"

int Server::parseCmd(const char *cmd, char *reply) {
   //does stuff 
}   


int Server::copystring(char *dst, const char *src) {
    // does stuff
    return (int) ((std::string) dst).length();
}


void Server::hello() {
    std::cout << "Server says 'hello'." << std::endl;
}


void *Server::tcp_server(void * dummy) {
    const char *port = "5555";
    // does a lot of stuff
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "tcpserver.hpp"

int main() {
    Server server;
    server.hello();  // 'Canary' method FIRST ERROR 

    // Initialize and set thread joinable
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    pthread_t serverthread;
    int rc;
    // **** tcp_server method must be static ****
    rc = pthread_create(&serverthread, NULL,  server.tcp_server, NULL);
        if (rc){
          std::cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << std::endl;
          exit(-1);
        }
    std::cout << "Main() started thread."  << std::endl;
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    void *status;
        rc = pthread_join(serverthread, &status);
        if (rc){
          std::cout << "Error:unable to join," << rc << std::endl;
          exit(-1);
        }


    return 0 ;
}
```

`makefile`:

```
all :  main.o tcpserver.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -o tcpserver main.o tcpserver.o 

tcpserver.o: tcpserver.cpp tcpserver.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 tcpserver.hpp

main.o  : main.cpp tcpserver.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lpthread

clean: 
    rm -f tcpserver.o main.o tcpserver
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Also, `__TCP_SERVER_HPP_INCLUDED__` is a reserved name - don't use double underscores.

Comment: It's a bit weird (allowed, but weird) to be calling static functions via a class instance. Do you really intend for those functions to be static?

Comment: Not related, but you can use `std::thread` from C++11 onwards. `pthread` now just looks yuck! :)

Comment: @GManNickG In Main 'pthread_create' apparently requires a static function.

Comment: @Arunmu I was unable to get std::thread to work from the examples I found.

Comment: @Barry Thanks, I just overlooked the underscores.  I've changed them .

Comment: @NateLockwood Please don't edit your question to incorporate answers you've received. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your object file compilation is incorrect:

```
tcpserver.o: tcpserver.cpp tcpserver.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 tcpserver.hpp

main.o  : main.cpp tcpserver.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lpthread
```

These rules don't indicate that you're building object files, they both say that they're independently building and linking applications. That's why you're getting linker errors - you're not actually linking the result of compiling `main.cpp` with `tcpserver.o`.

You need to provide `-c` to tell gcc that you don't want to link, that you're *just* compiling. You also need to provide `-o` to tell it where to output the results. Lastly, you're trying to compile `tcpserver.hpp` instead of `tcpserver.cpp`:

```
tcpserver.o: tcpserver.cpp tcpserver.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c tcpserver.cpp -o tcpserver.o

main.o  : main.cpp tcpserver.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

Or, shorter:

```
%.o : %.cpp tcpserver.hpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c $< -o $@
```

---

Also, this rule is bad:

```
all :  main.o tcpserver.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -o tcpserver main.o tcpserver.o
```

The target of the rule is `all`, but it's actually making a file named `tcpserver`. So if you keep rerunning `make`, it'll keep rebuilding `tcpserver` since the file `all` will continue to not exist. Change the target to match the actual target. And this is where your linker flags go:

```
tcpserver :  main.o tcpserver.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -o tcpserver $^ -lpthread
```

---

Additionally, the include guard you're using (`__TCP_SERVER_HPP_INCLUDED__`) is a reserved name for the C++ standard library. Any name which contains a double underscore or starts with an underscore followed by a capital letter should not be used in your code.

Comment: I'll admit to being SUPER-rusty with makefiles (primarily a VS dev these days) but are the .hpp files necessary to be listed in the makefile?  I didn't think they were as long as your include directories were done correctly, and included correctly in the .cpp files, which IMO it looks like it is in what the OP put up there.  And might they also need `-lpthread` or no?

Comment: @KevinAnderson They add dependencies for make. So if tcpserver.hpp is updated, main.o will need to be rebuilt. They're necessary to make sure you rebuild things correctly - although you wouldn't want to hand-write them.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, this is a compilation problem, with `-lpthread` at the wrong place.

I recommand using a simpler `Makefile`, taking advantage of default rules, dependancies, etc. and also setting all sorts of warnings

```
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
LDFLAGS = -lpthread

tcpserver: main.o tcpserver.o
    $(LINK.cc) $^ -o $@

clean: 
    rm -f tcpserver.o main.o tcpserver

# DO NOT DELETE

main.o: tcpserver.hpp
tcpserver.o: tcpserver.hpp
```

Note: the last 4 lines (starting with DO NOT DELETE) about dependancies were automagically added to the Makefile by the command

```
makedepend -Y *.cpp
```

These warnings will be helpful to fix errors:

```
 tcpserver.cpp: In static member function ‘static int Server::parseCmd(const char*, char*)’:
    tcpserver.cpp:14:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }   
 ^
tcpserver.cpp: At global scope:
tcpserver.cpp:12:34: warning: unused parameter ‘cmd’ [-Wunused-parameter]
     int Server::parseCmd(const char *cmd, char *reply) {
                                      ^
tcpserver.cpp:12:45: warning: unused parameter ‘reply’ [-Wunused-parameter]
     int Server::parseCmd(const char *cmd, char *reply) {
                                             ^
tcpserver.cpp:17:47: warning: unused parameter ‘src’ [-Wunused-parameter]
     int Server::copystring(char *dst, const char *src) {
                                                   ^
tcpserver.cpp: In static member function ‘static void* Server::tcp_server(void*)’:
tcpserver.cpp:29:17: warning: unused variable ‘port’ [-Wunused-variable]
     const char *port = "5555";
                     ^
tcpserver.cpp:31:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
tcpserver.cpp: At global scope:
tcpserver.cpp:28:33: warning: unused parameter ‘dummy’ [-Wunused-parameter]
     void *Server::tcp_server(void * dummy) {
```

Comment: make dies with 'missing separator'.

Comment: In the Makefile, spaces were inserted in order to comply with the Markdown syntax for in-line code. Please replace them with tabulations.